# How to extract only columns which has non zero values in mysql and php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am  trying to extract and display on web page, only non zero columns from mysql database. which ever column's date is 0000-00-00,i dont want to dispaly those columns on web page.
Below is the HTML code and php script respectively

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<p>
<lable>ENTER SO NUMBER</lable>
<input type="text"  name="soid" id="soid" >
</p>
<p><button><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/harwen/pleasant/256/Search-icon.png"  height="50" />SEARCH</button></p>
</form>
</html>
```

PHP script,

```
<?php

$userinput1 = $_POST['soid'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "status";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
   }

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1'  ") or die(mysqli_error
        ($conn));
echo "<p><font size= 4>SO_NUMBER:$userinput1";

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<style>
th{
color: blue;
}

td{
color: black;
}
</style>

<th>Sample Recived</th>
<th>Mol-Bio Extraction</th>
<th>Extraction QC</th>
<th>Library Prep</th>
<th>Library QC</th>
<th>Sequencing</th>
<th>Data Check</th>
<th>RE Sequencing</th>
<th>QC Check</th>
<th>Analysis Started</th>
<th>Analysis Completed</th>
<th>Report</th>
<th>Outbound</th>
 </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
       echo "<br />";
    echo "Department:".$row['dept'] ;
    echo "<td>" . $row['samplerecived'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextraction'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextractionqc'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['libraryprep'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['libraryqc'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sequencing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['datacheck'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['resequencing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['qccheck'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['analysisstarted'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['analysiscompleted'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['report'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['outbound'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Now i am getting all column displayed on web page, i need only those columns which has date recorded not 0000-00-00 recorded column.
this is the mysql table. 
[image]
 Output i am getting is
[image]
i want to display only non zero columns.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just selecting where the column isn't that doesn't work? `where \`date\` <> '0000-00-00'` Also note you are open to SQL injections with this code. You should use parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Have you tried adding a WHERE clause to your MYSQL e.g `WHERE date_recorded != '0000-00-00'` On top of that as a hint you want to look into using params in your SQL statement. right now your very open to SQL injection attacks. Try using PDO

Comment: @Catharsis `mysqli` supports prepared statements, OP just isn't using them.

Comment: @chris85 yep you're right, I didn't check that before I posted the comment :)

Comment: is it possible to do so??

Comment: What do mean by "so"; to do what? Use prepared statements?

Comment: what i am asking is, is it possible to get only non zero columns from the database for perticular user input(SO_Number)??

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions for the same problem. If you feel the need to add more information to an existing question, edit it instead.

Comment: kindly understand the question before commenting it as a duplicate sir

Comment: Kindly explain how your other questions are not duplicates.

Comment: In this question i am just printing non zero column data with empty column name, in my new question i want to print only non zero columns, if column data is empty than dont print that column name also. this is how my questions are different from each other.
Kindly understand the question before comment it as duplicate, got it?

Comment: [Q1:  "i need to display only non zero fields"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31508577/1446005), [Q2: "I want to display only non zero columns"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31513736/1446005), Current question: "i want to display only non zero columns". You may want to rephrase, as it kind of looks like duplicates to me. If you disagree, feel free to open a discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1' AND date_column <> '0000-00-00' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Although, with mysql you may even be able to do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1' AND date_column > '0000-00-00' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

I can see what you want now that you amended the question :)
Unfortunately I do not know of a way to what you want using SQL (someone may).

You are outputting the column headings and so not outputting a particular column would cause them to appear in the wrong columns so you will just have to output nothing where time is 0000-00-00

This is how I would do it in PHP though. (and if I have missed your point again I may shoot myself :))

```
<?php
    $userinput1 = $_POST['soid'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $dbname     = "status";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1'  ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $arrayHeadings = array(
        "dept"                  => "Department", 
        "samplerecived"         => "Sample Recived",
        "molbioextraction"      => "Mol-Bio Extraction",
        "molbioextractionqc"    => "Extraction QC",
        "libraryprep"           => "Library Prep",
        "libraryqc"             => "Library QC",
        "sequencing"            => "Sequencing",
        "datacheck"             => "Data Check",
        "resequencing"          => "RE Sequencing",
        "qccheck"               => "QC Check",
        "analysisstarted"       => "Analysis Started",
        "analysiscompleted"     => "Analysis Completed",
        "report"                => "Report",
        "outbound"              => "Outbound",
    );

?>
<style>
    th{
        color: blue;
    }

    td{
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($arrayHeadings as $key => $name): ?>
            <th><?= $name; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
            <?php foreach($arrayHeadings as $key => $name): ?>
                <?php if($row[$key] != "0000-00-00"): ?>
                    <td><?= $row[$key]; ?></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <td></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

The table headings are not output if the field contains 0000-00-00.
This relies on only one element being output at a time.

```
<?php
    $userinput1 = $_POST['soid'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $dbname     = "status";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1'  ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $arrayHeadings = array(
        "dept"                  => "Department", 
        "samplerecived"         => "Sample Recived",
        "molbioextraction"      => "Mol-Bio Extraction",
        "molbioextractionqc"    => "Extraction QC",
        "libraryprep"           => "Library Prep",
        "libraryqc"             => "Library QC",
        "sequencing"            => "Sequencing",
        "datacheck"             => "Data Check",
        "resequencing"          => "RE Sequencing",
        "qccheck"               => "QC Check",
        "analysisstarted"       => "Analysis Started",
        "analysiscompleted"     => "Analysis Completed",
        "report"                => "Report",
        "outbound"              => "Outbound",
    );

?>
<style>
    th{
        color: blue;
    }

    td{
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($arrayHeadings as $key => $name): ?>
            <?php if($row[$key] != "0000-00-00"): ?>
                <th><?= $name; ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
            <?php foreach($arrayHeadings as $key => $name): ?>
                <?php if($row[$key] != "0000-00-00"): ?>
                    <td><?= $row[$key]; ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i didnt have separate column for date, i am inserting timestamp in the columns as specified in <th>.

Comment: Apologies, I may be tired but I do not see anything that indicates where you are getting the date from. Did this work either way?

Comment: i am getting date from predefined DATE keyword and stroing it in perticular column