# How to display only non zero fields in mysql through php and HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]

Above image is the entry of data in mysql database.

[image]

Above image was the output what i am getting is,

But i need to display only non zero fields as the output that means from "sample revived" column to "library qc" column only.

php script is

```
<?php

$userinput1 = $_POST['soid'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "status";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1'  ") or die(mysqli_error
    ($conn));
echo "<p><font size= 4>SO_NUMBER:$userinput1";

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<style>
th{
color: blue;
}

td{
color: black;
}
</style>

<th>Sample Recived</th>
<th>Mol-Bio Extraction</th>
<th>Extraction QC</th>
<th>Library Prep</th>
<th>Library QC</th>
<th>Sequencing</th>
<th>Data Check</th>
<th>RE Sequencing</th>
<th>QC Check</th>
<th>Analysis Started</th>
<th>Analysis Completed</th>
<th>Report</th>
<th>Outbound</th>
 </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
echo "<tr>";
   echo "<br />";
echo "Department:".$row['dept'] ;
echo "<td>" . $row['samplerecived'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextraction'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextractionqc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['libraryprep'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['libraryqc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sequencing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['datacheck'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['resequencing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['qccheck'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['analysisstarted'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['analysiscompleted'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['report'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['outbound'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Comment: if field = 0000-00-00 dont echo it

Comment: its DATE field , how to echo only DATE field??

Comment: you should use IF condition or Ternary Operator !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your while loop use for each field like this (use like this for all fields):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {

if($row['samplerecived']=="0000-00-00") $row['samplerecived']="";

echo "<tr>";
   echo "<br />";
echo "Department:".$row['dept'] ;
echo "<td>" . $row['samplerecived'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextraction'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['molbioextractionqc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['libraryprep'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['libraryqc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sequencing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['datacheck'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['resequencing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['qccheck'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['analysisstarted'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['analysiscompleted'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['report'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['outbound'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get u r point !!! if possible can you explain briefly??

Comment: if the value of field is 0000-00-00 then that field will be equal to blank ("")

Answer (score 0):

Use typecasting operator `int()` for the respective fields.

```
$var = (int) $var ? $var : '';
```

**Explanation:**

An empty date `0000-00-00 00:00:00` always return `0` which is blank/empty.

In above code, it will return `0` hence, it will not display blank/empty date.

Only dates with some non-zero values will be displayed.

Comment: set below query in mysqli_query
SELECT 
soid,dept,
if(samplerecived='0000-00-00' OR samplerecived='','',samplerecived) as samplerecived,
if(molbioextraction='0000-00-00' OR molbioextraction='','',molbioextraction) as molbioextraction,
if(molbioextractionqc='0000-00-00' OR molbioextractionqc='','',molbioextractionqc) as molbioextractionqc,
if(librayqc='0000-00-00' OR librayqc='','',librayqc) as librayqc,  
if(sequncing='0000-00-00' OR sequncing='','',sequncing) as sequncing,
if(datacheck='0000-00-00' OR datacheck='','',datacheck) as datacheck,
FROM $dbname.statusinfo WHERE soid = '$userinput1'